# How to deploy a Wikipedia-like Mediawiki (with all extensions configured in the same way)

Tags: mediawiki

Is there a fast way to make my own Mediawiki looks the same as Wikipedia.org?

I mean, adds all extensions wikipedia.org is using. and configure it with the same way wikipedia has. Is there a list?

Comment: Amazing there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Special:Version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aVersion#mw-version-ext) page lists all of the installed extensions for a MediaWiki instance. Also see http://noc.wikimedia.org/conf/ for example of real configuration employing all these extensions, though using it directly would be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to configure the same namespaces that Wikipedia uses.

When installing Mediawiki name your project Wikipedia since Mediawiki calls namespace number four your project name and Wikipedia calls that namespace Wikipedia.

The rest of the namespaces and aliases you will need to configure are here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_namespace

Example of creating the Portal: and Book: namespaces:

```
define("NS_PORTAL", 100);
define("NS_PORTAL_TALK", 101);

$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_PORTAL] = "Portal";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_PORTAL_TALK] = "Portal_talk";   // underscore required

$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_PORTAL] = array( 'editportal' ); //permission "editportal" required to edit the portal namespace
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_PORTAL] = true;            //subpages enabled for the portal namespace
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['editportal'] = true;      //permission "editportal" granted to users in the "sysop" group

$wgContentNamespaces[] = NS_PORTAL;

### Wikipedia Book Namespace 108/109

define("NS_BOOK", 108);
define("NS_BOOK_TALK", 109);

$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_BOOK] = "Book";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_BOOK_TALK] = "Book_talk";   // underscore required

$wgNamespaceProtection[NS_BOOK] = array( 'editbook' ); //permission "editbook" required to edit the book namespace
$wgNamespacesWithSubpages[NS_BOOK] = true;            //subpages enabled for the book namespace
$wgGroupPermissions['sysop']['editbook'] = true;      //permission "editbook" granted to users in the "sysop" group

$wgContentNamespaces[] = NS_BOOK;
```

Wikipedia uses hundreds of templates.  Learn to use Special:Export to fetch them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any fast, complete way to do this, but you might try copying the [MediaWiki:Common.css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aCommon.css) and [MediaWiki:Common.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aCommon.js) files from Wikipedia onto your own site (under the same page names). Install whatever extensions you need, e.g. Cite.php, and use [Special:Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport) to export template files that you want (this is a pretty quick batch process) and your own wiki's Special:Import page to grab them. Hope this helps.